# How to use jquery selectors to get the third or fourth element and set its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to get the third or forth element and set its id.

I found that:

```
$('#menu li:first').attr('id', 'test')
```

its actually working but I only get the first element. On the other hand I tried to use the following but it is not working.

```
$('#menu li').get(0).attr('id', 'test')
```

Can someone explain how to get the desirable element? (eg 4 or 5) and set its id and why the second bunch of code it's not working?

Comment: The `.get()` function returns the DOM element itself, rather than a jQuery object that contains the DOM element, so you can't call jQuery functions (such as `.attr()`) on it. As the answers have already pointed out, the `.eq()` function is intended for that.

Comment: For the record, both of the answers below are correct, if you are curious why `get` is not giving you what you want it is because the `get` function returns the native `DOMElement` as opposed to the wrapped jQuery set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `eq()` method:

```
$('#menu li').eq(2).attr('id', 'third') // selects third element
$('#menu li').eq(3).attr('id', 'fourth') // selects fourth element
```

Comment: How do you assign same id to two different elements?

Comment: @thecodeparadox, yep, ids should be different from each other.

Comment: are you sure `eq(4) and eq(5)` target `third and fourth` element? I think it should target the `fifth and sixth` element.

Comment: no, i'm sure that you are scrutinizing ma code :) , thanks btw.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `.eq` function.

```
$('#menu li').eq(4).attr(...)
```

or

```
$('#menu li:eq(4)').attr(...)
```

On a side note `.get(0)` return you a DOM element and not jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#menu li:eq(3)').attr('id', 'id_4');
$('#menu li:eq(4)').attr('id', 'id_5');
```

or

```
$('#menu li').eq(3).attr('id', 'id_4');
$('#menu li').eq(4).attr('id', 'id_5');
```

`eq()` or `:eq()` both take a parameter index of target element and it is always

`targetElementIndex - 1`. Because it is Zero based.

So, if you target 4th or 5th element then you have to gives arguments as 3 and 4.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/24/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, get() returns the DOM element.

It is possible to set the id of an element without using jquery's `attr()`.

```
$('#menu li').get(3).id = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu')
```

selects element with the id "menu".

```
$('#menu li')
```

or

```
$('#menu').find('li')
```

selects all it's `<li>` descendants and

```
$('#menu li').eq(3)
```

selects the fourth (as they are labeled from zero).

Note also that

```
$('#menu li')[3]
```

will get the HTMLElement itself, instead of its jQuery wrapper.